# Connecting IBM Cloud php app to IBM Cloud DB2

Tags: php, db2, ibm-cloud, buildpack

During the IBM Cloud Foundy upgrade to cflinuxfs3 a few things got missed, including providing a way to connect IBM Cloud php app to IBM Cloud DB2.

The provided buildpacks do not support DB2 connections and the instructions on IBM Knowledge Center are no longer valid.

Anyone knows how to connect IBM Cloud php app to IBM Cloud DB2 after the Sept 16th upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

If your cloud solution does not supply a working extension for Db2 to work with your PHP in your chosen environment, that is not a matter for StackOverflow.

Instead, Use the github issues page(s) to work with your buildpack supplier and cloud vendor to build the required extension with the required toolchain, or pay someone to do the build and test and deploy to your instances.

If you use an IBM Db2 driver and and IBM written Db2 extension for PHP, then it is a CLI / ODBC application, and because of that, the *configuration*  for SSL needs to follow the [IBM-documented](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_cli_and_odbc_applications.html) steps - all of which have the pre-requisite that you have a working PHP extension for Db2 that works in your environment, along with other pre-reqs.